# Cannot save user ID to database

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo, save

I'm pretty much a novice when it comes to coding, so sorry for lack of knowledge here.

I'm trying to retrive a forigne key attribute from one database table (the user's ID number) so I can then make that **`id`** a variable which will be used to save the details into another database table.

From that I can view all of the saved records linked with that user's id when they are logged in.

My problem is with getting the user ID and making it a variable to save into the database, I just can't seem to make it work. The rest of the code works if I remove the user ID but I need that to save into the table.

Here's my code:

```
require_once( "dbconnect.php" );
try 
{
  $db = getConnection();    
  function get_id($db) 
  {   
    $username= $_SESSION['username'];
    $result = $db->query(
        "SELECT userID FROM users where username='$username'");
    return $result;
  }
  $uID = get_id($db); 

  $userID= $uID->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
  $title = $Result->title;
  $desp = $Result->description;

  $sql = "INSERT INTO saved (userID, title, desp
          VALUES ('$userID', '$title', '$desp')";
```

Comment: When you look at your code, despite being a novice - what do you think happens to variable `$userID` (which seems to be what you want) if you use `$uID->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);`? You're calling `setFetchMode` for which documentation says that it either returns true or false. Is it true or false you need or a number in `$userID` variable? :)

Comment: i need a number, they are auto-assigned when a user is added to the database from 1+ i currently have 5 accounts so i have 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 but i only get 1

Comment: Then it seems you are using the wrong function here. Is it maybe `fetchColumn` that you might need?

Comment: just change it to $userID= $uID->setFetchMode(PDO::fetchColumn);    and got "Undefined class constant 'fetchColumn' in"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way

```
function get_subid($db,$username) 
{   
    $stm = $db->prepare("SELECT userID FROM users where username=?");
    $stm->execute(array($username));
    return $stm->fetchColumn();
}
$userID = get_subid($db,$_SESSION['username']);
```

Comment: this worked however i'm having the issue of 'duplicate entry' when i try to save another item. is this an issue with the foreign key in the sql database or???

Comment: you may ask another question then, regarding this duplicate entry error, providing as much relevant information as possible.

Answer (score -1):

try removing the quotes around userid variable in your query :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO saved (userID, title, desp) VALUES ($userID, '$title', '$desp')";
```

Comment: hey thanks that did save however it's only getting the userID 1, when i log into another account say with user ID 2 it still tries to save 1. any advice?

Comment: cfr comment from N.B. on your question ... + my answer :-)

Comment: A good advice would be reading the comment of @N.B. under your question.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
require_once( "dbconnect.php" ); 
try { 
/** * ** connect using the getConnection function written in myfunctions.php ** */ $db = getConnection();

function get_subid($db) {
$username= $_SESSION['username']; //variable accessed through the function 
$query = $db->query("SELECT userID FROM users where username='$username'");

$row = $query->row(); //Get's the first Row
$result = $row->userID; //Get's the field userID of this first row
return $result; 
} 
$uID = get_subid($db);

            $title = $Result->title;
            $desp = $Result->description;

            // insert into database
$data = array(
  'userID' => $uID,
  'title' => $title,
  'desp' => $desp
);
$db->insert('saved', $data);
```

This should be what you'd like (see the comments)